Pandas read_excel (or other) - does `skiprows` occur before `headers`?
This is a question about the order in which two operations occur when the Pandas read_excel function is called. (Although this would also apply to other read_X type functions such as read_csv.)
The read_excel function takes two arguments of interest

skiprows
headers

In this case, I pass a list of integers to headers to create a multiindex.
My question is, does the skiprows operation occur before headers is used to set the headers? (The documentation doesn't explicitly state anything about this.)
For context, I have some code which reads an Excel file which contains blank lines before the header rows, and between the header rows and data. In this context it isn't obvious what the behavior should be.

I do not think the order of operations even matters when reading excel. If you specify a header argument, then no matter how many rows you skip the header will be defined. If you do not specify a header argument, pandas will assume the first row as the header.

@iBeMeltin Yes, that would certainly make a lot of sense. In this context, especially with a multiindex, it could have been that the header was constructed and then skiprows was used to remove components from the header. It would be a bit of a strange API. Where it does become more ambiguous is if there are blank lines, as in the example I happen to be working with. If there are blank lines it is no longer obvious what the behavior should be.

Yes, when using an integer, skiprows skips the rows in the beginning of the file, independently of the header. See for example read_csv's doc:

skiprows  int, list of int or Callable, optional
Line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file.
If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the row indices, returning True if the row should be skipped and False
otherwise. An example of a valid callable argument would be lambda x:
x in [0, 2].

Example:
import io

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12'''), skiprows=2, header=None)

    0   1   2
0   7   8   9
1  10  11  12

pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('''1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
10,11,12'''), skiprows=2, header=0)

    7   8   9
0  10  11  12


The documentation doesn't explicitly state this operation happens before headers is selected. From your answer it seems like you are assuming, as I am also inclined to assume, that skiprows is the first operation which is performed?

@FreelanceConsultant it says "at the start of the file", my understanding is that it first discards those n rows then resumes as if they never existed (in my example header=0 thus gets the first row after the 2 skipped rows).

Yes, in Pandas, the skiprows operation occurs before the headers are set when using the read_excel function (and similarly for other read_X functions like read_csv).
